# How to do UnitOfWork + Repository patterns with entity framework core and unit testing

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

I'm running into an issue while unit testing where if I run multiple tests at once, the `DbContext` will lose track of records I've added during unit tests and I think this may have to do with how services are registered in my `ServiceCollection`.

I have the following setup:

IUnitOfWork:

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        IUserRepository Users { get; }

        int Complete();
    }
```

UnitOfWork

```
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;

        public IUserRepository Users { get; }

        public UnitOfWork(MyDbContext context,
                          IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            _context = context;

            Users = userRepository;
        }

        public void Dispose() => _context.Dispose();

        public int Complete() => _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

UserRepository

```
    public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(MyDbContext context) : base(context) { }

        public MyDbContext MyDbContext => Context as MyDbContext;

        public Task<User?> GetUserDetailsAsync(int userID)
        {
            var user = MyDbContext.Users.Where(user => user.Id == userID)
                                                  .Include(user => user.Emails)
                                                  .Include(user => user.PhoneNumbers).FirstOrDefault();

            return Task.FromResult(user);
        }
    }
```

Here is my base test:

```
    public abstract class BaseTest : IDisposable
    {
        protected ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

        private MyDbContext MyDbContext { get; }

        protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }

        public BaseTest()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>()
                             .AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>()
                             .AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>))
                             .AddScoped<IOrganizationRepository, OrganizationRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<IExercisePostRepository, ExercisePostRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>()
                             .AddTransient<IRestClient, RestClient>()
                             .AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
                             .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                                                                  options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Core")
                                                                         .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
            ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            SpotcheckrCoreContext = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
            MyDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
            UnitOfWork = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            MyDbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            UnitOfWork.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Sample test:

```
    public class UserServiceTests : BaseTest
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

        private readonly IUserService Service;

        public UserServiceTests()
        {
            UnitOfWork = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();
            Service = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void GetUserAsync_WithValidUser_ReturnsUser()
        {
            var user = new User
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe"
            };
            UnitOfWork.Users.Add(user);
            UnitOfWork.Complete();

            var result = await Service.GetUserAsync(user.Id);
            Assert.Equal(user.Id, result.Id);
        }
}
```

If I run this test by itself, then it will correctly pass and I can see the user in the repository. However if I run it with other tests and debug, then that user is lost once I inspect UnitOfWork.Users in the repository but I do see it in the UnitOfWork.Users in the test.

What is the correct approach here?

Edit 1:
Tried some other changes but no luck yet. Adjusted `UnitOfWork` to take in the interfaces of each repository and registering them in `BaseTest` as scoped services. Also tried marking `BaseTest` as implementing `IDisposable` and then executing:

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            MyDbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            UnitOfWork.Dispose();
        }
```

In the service layer I'll see the Users just fine but as soon as I step into the repository layer I'll lose the Users :/ I have a suspicion it is related to dependency injection `AddScoped` vs `AddTransient` and how all of that works with running multiple unit tests.

Edit 2:
Tried some more things...Used `IClassFixture<BaseTest>` on each test class and then ensured that each test class implemented `IDisposable` and in there I would ensure the Context database was deleted; also ensured in the test class constructor that it was created. With this I ended up with the following error:

`The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked`

And so I added `.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)` but the problem still persisted.

This is very annoying to setup.

Answer (score 1):

This is what has resolved it for me for now.

Summary: Created a new `ServiceFixture`. This `ServiceFixture` is applied to a `BaseTest` class as `IClassFixture<ServiceFixture>`. The `ServiceFixture` is responsible for initializing the service collection and allowing for it to be reused across different test classes. The purpose of the `BaseTest` is to allow for disposal of the database and other clean up that is necessary after each test. The `Dispose` method of this class will detach entity state and also delete the database.

ServiceFixture.cs

```
public class ServiceFixture
    {
        public ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; }

        public ServiceFixture()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>()
                             .AddScoped<ICertificationService, CertificationService>()
                             .AddScoped<IOrganizationService, OrganizationService>()
                             .AddScoped<ICertificateService, CertificateService>()
                             .AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>()
                             .AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<IExercisePostRepository, ExercisePostRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<IEmailRepository, EmailRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<IPhoneNumberRepository, PhoneNumberRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<ICertificationRepository, CertificationRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<ICertificateRepository, CertificateRepository>()
                             .AddScoped<IOrganizationRepository, OrganizationRepository>()
                             .AddTransient<IRestClient, RestClient>()
                             .AddSingleton<NASMCertificationValidator>()
                             .AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
                             .AddDbContext<SpotcheckrCoreContext>(options =>
                                                                  options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Spotcheckr-Core")
                                                                         .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
                                                                         .EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
            ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

BaseTest.cs

```
    public abstract class BaseTest : IClassFixture<ServiceFixture>, IDisposable
    {
        protected readonly ServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

        protected readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;

        private readonly SpotcheckrCoreContext Context;

        public BaseTest(ServiceFixture serviceFixture)
        {
            ServiceProvider = serviceFixture.ServiceProvider;
            Context = serviceFixture.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SpotcheckrCoreContext>();
            UnitOfWork = serviceFixture.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUnitOfWork>();

            Context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(entry => entry.State = EntityState.Detached);
            Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }
    }
```

UserServiceTests.cs

```
    public class UserServiceTests : BaseTest
    {
        private readonly IUserService Service;

        public UserServiceTests(ServiceFixture serviceFixture) : base(serviceFixture)
        {
            Service = serviceFixture.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void GetUserAsync_WithInvalidUser_ThrowsException()
        {
            Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidOperationException>(() => Service.GetUserAsync(-1));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CreateUser_UserTypeAthlete_CreatesAthleteUser()
        {
            var result = Service.CreateUser(Models.UserType.Athlete);
            Assert.IsType<Athlete>(result);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CreateUser_UserTypePersonalTrainer_CreatesPersonalTrainerUser()
        {
            var result = Service.CreateUser(Models.UserType.PersonalTrainer);
            Assert.IsType<PersonalTrainer>(result);
        }
    }
```